# Problems express router

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

This router have to return the same result every time i execute it, but it sometimes returns different results.
Why the variable results sometimes return a value, and sometimes return a different value?

```
app.get('/infostocks',function(req,res){

   Stock.find({},{_id:0,__v:0},
     function(err,data){
        if(err) throw (err);

        var result =  [];
        result.push(data);
        console.log(data.length);

        for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){

          var now = moment().format("YYYY-MM-D");
          var now7=moment().subtract(7, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-D");
          yahooFinance.historical({
            symbol: data[i].id_stock,
            from: now7,
            to: now,
            // period: 'd'  
            // 'd' (daily), 'w' (weekly), 'm' (monthly), 'v' (dividends only)
          }, 
          function (err, quotes) {

            if(err) return res.send("Errore"+err);
            if(quotes.length>0){
              console.log(i);
              result.push(quotes);
              if(i==data.length-1)
               res.send(result);
            } else{
              res.send("Code not valid");
            }      
          });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I haven't changed any data in the Stocks table.

Comment: Please provide the sample Stock document.

Comment: A stock Document is like this

Comment: {_id:1234,id_stock:"AAPL"}

Comment: maybe a problem in the i in the for loop?

Comment: `yahooFinance.historical` isn't sync. You should use `async.each` as a loop instead of you `for`